# How do I host an active STS in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I'm attempting to host an active STS endpoint in my ASP.NET MVC 4 site (which already successfully hosts a passive STS endpoint). For some reason, the WCF runtime does not seem to be "handling" calls to my servive URI.

In my RouteConfig.cs file, I have this:

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("tokens", new MyTokenServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyTokenServiceConfiguration)));
```

That, I believe, is the correct way to host a service without a .svc file. In my web.config file, I have this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <!--(behaviors etc)-->
    <services>
        <service name="System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustServiceContract">
            <endpoint address="" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13SyncContract"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This hunk of configuration can be successfully used to self-host the service, the only thing I have changed is the address of the endpoint.

When I attempt to call the service, I get:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings.

Logged in the service trace is:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
>   There was no channel that could accept the message with action 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue'.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/blob/master/src/Libraries/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Protocols/WSTrust/TokenServiceHostFactory.cs

and

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/blob/master/src/OnPremise/WebSite/App_Start/ProtocolConfig.cs

for a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

Claims-based identities in ASP.NET MVC 4.5 using the standard ASP.NET providers,

http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/03/27/Claims-based-identities-in-ASPNET-MVC-45-using-the-standard-ASPNET-providers.aspx

Building a simple custom STS using VS2012 & ASP.NET MVC

http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/04/09/Building-a-simple-custom-STS-using-VS2012-ASPNET-MVC.aspx